# Can 'ping' requests still be used for a DoS attack?

Tags: windows, networking, security, ping

I was reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/318870/why-do-companies-block-ping), and couldn't help noticing this part of one of the answers:

> On the Internet, ping of death is a denial of service (DoS) attack caused by an attacker > deliberately sending an IP packet larger than the 65,536 bytes allowed by the IP protocol.
>
> One of the features of TCP/IP is fragmentation; it allows a single IP
> packet to be broken down into smaller segments. In 1996, attackers
> began to take advantage of that feature when they found that a packet
> broken down into fragments could add up to more than the allowed
> 65,536 bytes. Many operating systems didn't know what to do when they
> received an oversized packet, so they froze, crashed, or rebooted.

That was 1996, but is it still effective today?

The reason behind this question is because I help out with a gameserver community, and one of their gameservers has recently been the target of repeated DoS attacks, but these DoS attacks crash the gameserver.

The internet connection of the dedicated server that the gameserver is hosted on does not suffer, and is not degraded.

I have used Wireshark to sniff out these attack packets, and it turns out to be just one ICMP ping request to the gameserver's port (I didn't actually know it's possible could ping a specific port...).

I had already suspected that it was a packet that was specifically engineered to crash the gameserver, but is it possible in modern computing that a oversize ping packet crash the gameserver?

Lastly, if the dedicated server stopped responding to ICMP requests (aka, it is blocked in the firewall), would this type of exploit still be possible?

Comment: You're asking questions that you're in the best position to answer. You have the packet data, we don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As far as I know, Wireshark cannot determine the size of a packet, so I am unsure whether it was an oversized packet that caused the gameserver to crash, or whether it was a cleverly-engineered standard game packet.

Comment: Let us look at it and see

Comment: @Paul Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oxCtiOV-NEMzN3YUJJa1hESURnSGtMVHZjUVBYWGNTdFZ3/edit?usp=sharing . You're looking for the IP 144.76.160.241.

Comment: @Paul https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oxCtiOV-NETGxybEVFQ1V4UHR0dU5rVUpSOTRyX2pDWWtN/edit?usp=sharing